# VBA Import Picture

Tags: vba

I made a tool in Excel 2011 on my Mac but when I want to try the tool on a Windows with Excel 2013 there is an error.

I am importing a picture in a specific cell but the error is: `Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture class`on this line: `Set Pic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(.Value)`

```
Sub Procedure4()
Dim Pic As Picture
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet.Range("J5")
    Set Pic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(.Value)
    With .Offset(2, -3)
        Pic.Top = .Top
        Pic.Left = .Left
        Pic.Height = .Height * 3
        Pic.Width = .Width * 3
    End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Doesn't Excel 2013 support this anymore or is there something wrong?